Understanding "equality" in Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality (CSI) for two vectors $u = (u_{1} ~u_{2})^T$ and $v=(v_{1} ~v_{2})^T$ is given by
$$|u^\dagger v|^2 \le (u^\dagger u)(v^\dagger v)$$
It is intuitive to understand that the equality should hold when one vector is scalar multiple of other. However, in the matrix form where CSI reads
$$|tr(A^*B)|^2 \le tr(A^*A) tr(B^*B)$$
with $*$ denoting the transposed-conjugate, when does equality hold? In particular, I wanted to understand the condition given by eq (9) of this article as shown in the screenshot.

The trace defines a norm on the space of matrices via the formula you mentioned.  Therefore the boundary case of equality in Cauchy-Schwarz still has the same meaning: the matrices must be proportional (of course in your case the proportionality constant could be a complex scalar).

Thanks @MikhailKatz. As you can see neither $A$ nor $B$ has the term $Tr[\rho_\lambda \Pi_x L_\lambda]$ that appears in the denominator on $r.h.s.$ of (9).

@Mike The denominator in $A^{\dagger}$ is just a re-scaling factor, does not change the fact that $A$ and $B$ are just the cope of each other upon re-scaling, in order to attain the equality of CSI
